# Database Tools в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Не могу найти окно для работу с базами данных в IntelliJ IDEA [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у Вас Ultimate-версия?

Comment: @post_zeew Нет, community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте *Setting* (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> *Plugins*. Судя по всему, у вас не установлен плагин для работы с базами данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, вам нужно установить этот плагин.

Comment: Большое спасибо! It works!!!